# Antd 4 Checkbox doesn't have value after form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, antd

### What I have

I have an Ant Design 4 form with a checkbox in it:

```js
const Example = ({ initialValues, onSave }) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    form.resetFields();
  }, [initialValues.isAccepted]);

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
    onSave(values);
  };

  const getInitialValues = useCallback(() => ({
    isAccepted: initialValues.isAccepted || false,
  }));

  return (
    <Form form={form} onFinish={onFinish} initialValues={getInitialValues()}>
      <Form.Item name="isAccepted">
        <Checkbox>The company can use my data</Checkbox>
      </Form.Item>
      <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Save</Button>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

### Problem

The checkbox is always unchecked even if it is `true` inside `initialValues`. Also, when I submit the form the `values` variable always contains the value from `initialValues`, it doesn't registers that I changed (checked or unchecked) the checkbox.

### Goal

I would like the initial value to be set properly from `inititalValues` and get the current value of the checkbox in `onFinish`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### tl;dr

Add `valuePropName="checked"` to the `Form.Item` component:

```js
<Form.Item name="isAccepted" valuePropName="checked">
```

### Explanation

A checkbox's value is not stored in a `value` attribute like for text inputs. Instead, it has a `checked` attribute. You have to tell the `Form.Item` component to set that attribute/prop by telling the prop's name through `valuePropName`.

The docs on [`Form.Item`](https://ant.design/components/form#formitem) describes this prop:

> **`valuePropName`**: Props of children node, for example, the prop of Switch is 'checked'. This prop is an encapsulation of `getValueProps`, which will be invalid after customizing `getValueProps`

Later it describes how the wrapping happens:

> After wrapped by `Form.Item` with `name` property, `value` (or other property defined by `valuePropName`) `onChange` (or other property defined by `trigger`) props will be added to form controls, the flow of form data will be handled by Form...